# How to switch between nib views inside the same container Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, containers, nib

I have a container with a few reusable elements: imageView, label and a stackView.

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Constants

var stepList = [UIViewController]()

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet private(set) weak var logoImageview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet private(set) weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private(set) weak var progressStackView: UIStackView!

. . .
}
```

I also have another three viewControllers designed with Nib files, let's call them oneVC, twoVC and threeVC. This is how they look:

```
class StepOneViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Constants
. . .

@IBOutlet private(set) weak var nextButton: UIButton!

. . .
}
```

Each controller has it's own nextButton, and it's own IBAction to trigger when that button is tapped. It should make a push to the next viewController, but that's not happening.

When you access the container, the oneVC is displayed among the reusable elements of the container. This works.

I don't know how to access each button of my controllers from my containerController. I need to achieve that to show the next nib, and it must be able to go back too.

This code from my ContainerViewController add each controller's view as a subview:

```
private func setupControllers() {
    stepList.append(StepOneViewController(nibName: "StepOneViewController", bundle: nil))
    stepList.append(StepTwoViewController(nibName: "StepTwoViewController", bundle: nil))
    stepList.append(StepThreeViewController(nibName: "StepThreeViewController", bundle: nil))

    guard let stepOneView   = stepList.first?.view,
          let stepTwoView   = stepList[1].view,
          let stepThreeView = stepList.last?.view
    else { return }
    
    configureStepViewsLayout(onStepView: stepOneView)
    
    
}

private func configureStepViewsLayout(onStepView stepView: UIView) {
    view.addSubview(stepView)
    stepView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stepView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressStackView.bottomAnchor,
                                         constant: 20),
        stepView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leftAnchor),
        stepView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.rightAnchor),
        stepView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

I also need to change the progressStackView color every time any nextButton is tapped and shows the next controller.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is totally illegal. You cannot simply say

```
view.addSubview(stepView)
```

out of the blue like that. You are effectively just using the nib as a form of dumpster diving; you are grabbing the view and shoving it into your interface, but the view controller (e.g. StepOneViewController) bears no formal relationship to your view controller (ContainerViewController). You are using the *word* "container", but this is *not* a container view controller.

There is an elaborate parent–child dance that you must do in order to get the child (e.g. StepOneViewController) into the *view controller hierarchy* and make your container view controller *be* a container view controller — and you are not doing the dance.

Once you do the dance, the child will be able to talk to the parent as its `parent`. The parent can then remove the child (again using a formal dance) and replace it with another.

Also, it's a really bad idea to retain three view controllers as you are doing. You only have one visible child view at a time so you only need one child view controller at any given moment.

Comment: Here's a downloadable example demonstrating the child-swapping dance: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p316containerController/ch19p631containerController/ViewController.swift